# How to play polyphonic Sounds in C#

Tags: c#, audio

I've been searching SO and Google for this for hours and can't find a solution to my thought-to-be simple problem. For a small point-and-click-game I develop for my daughter I have the following requirements:

- Play multiple Soundeffects (WAV or MP3, doesn't matter) simultaneously/polyphonic
- Must run on .Net 4.7 (not Core)
- No additional Libraries except .Net-Framework

Sounds simple? It obviously isn't:

- Soundplayer does only play ONE sound at a time, even with multiple instances, multiple threads and duplicated streams in memory
- MediaPlayer wants an URI as Input but I have a byte-array/stream containing Wav/MP3-Information
- DirectSound is outdated and available wrappers are also mostly outdated

I WILL NOT cache my stream to disk, just to load it in MediaPlayer (that's - surprisingly - a suggestion I've read often here on StackOverflow and that's a really bad practice).

Any Ideas?

P.S: If someone was able to input a stream/byte-array to System.Windows.Media.Mediaplayer - that would be an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: thank you. This would go against Requirement: "No additional Libraries". There would be others as well (like "Bass") which I am using in other projects.

Comment: You're probably right. Since I do not have time to implement a whole Audiomixer for such a small-scale-project, I'll probably just use Mono or Unity. Would have been fun though if possible in a really lightweight App...